# Is there a way to do LaTeX-style image insertions into MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, latex, pictures

I have to produce a document that changes every so often, but mostly just the images. I have a system for producing the images where, when I update images, I store them in a folder with an updated date, so the old pictures would be like Dave/Documents/20210409/myphoto1.png, and the newer ones would be like Dave/Documents/20210505/myphoto1.png.

If I were preparing this document in LaTeX, I could go to the file and just do "replace all" to swap out the old date for the new. When I recompile the document, the new images will be present in the PDF output.

Is there a way to mimic this in Word?

Comment: Do you mean the new picture replace the old one directly?

Comment: @Lee yes, replace the old images.

Comment: Have you looked into using the field INCLUDEPICTURE?  That inserts a linked field displaying your image (not sure if the image itself is embedded in the Word doc which may be an issue if you want to email that rather than PDF).  If you are replacing the entire set of images in the new folder, you could ALT F9 to view all field codes, and then use find and replace to change the old "date" part eg 20210409 and replace with 20210505, then ALT F9 to change back to field results, CTRL a to select all, and F9 to refresh fields, which should update all the images in the linked fields.

Comment: @Tanya that is extremely promising! Could you please expand on that? I am hitting ALT F9 but not seeing anything happen. Perhaps I did INCLUDEPICTURE wrong, as I have only ever done Insert > Picture to put pictures in a Word file.

Comment: Did you include the full path in the INCLUDEPICTURE field - it should look something like { INCLUDEPICTURE  "C:\\Dave\\Documents\\20210409\\myphoto1.png"  \\* MERGEFORMAT } (I'm assuming it's on C:\ drive but just change path to where your folder is).  NOTE:  You'll need double backslash \\ in the path in a field like this.

Comment: @Tanya I have gotten the INCLUDEPICTURE field to show and create pictures when I do ALT+F9, but they are not swapping out when I change the file name. Thoughts? I did wind up using an Excel file as a database (of sorts) to get INCLUDEPICTURE to insert the picture, though I have changed the file names in there, too.

Comment: @Tanya I don't quite feel like a Superuser for this, but I at least figure out a way to do my task. I use INSERTPICTURE and then, when I run my script, I overwrite the file. This is not 100% satisfying, and I want to know how to manipulate the date in the INSERTPICTURE line in Word, but I am excited to see my pictures changing in Word!

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  After you edited the fields with new path, did you try CTRL a (select all) and F9 (refresh all fields)?

Comment: @Tanya Here are my steps. 1) Generate five images, each with five versions, saved like `figure_i_version_j.png`. 2) In Word, Insert > Pictures > Link to File. 3) Change `{ INCLUDEPICTURE "figure_0_version_0.png" \* MERGEFOTMAR \d }` to `{ INCLUDEPICTURE "figure_0_version_1.png" \* MERGEFOTMAR \d }`. 4) CTRL + A, then F9. I am left with the original version of the image, even upon saving and reopening or saving as a PDF. Upon deleting the `figure_0_version_0.png` file, the Word file does not display an image for `{ INCLUDEPICTURE "figure_0_version_1.png" \* MERGEFOTMAR \d }`.

Comment: @Tanya I got it to work on a different computer, though it is strange that it did not work the first time.