# Is there a way to do LaTeX-style image insertions into Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, latex, pictures

I have to produce a slideshow that changes every so often, but mostly just the images. I have a system for producing the images where, when I update images, I store them in a folder with an updated date, so the old pictures would be like Dave/Documents/20220223/myphoto1.png, and the newer ones would be like Dave/Documents/20220225/myphoto1.png.

If I were preparing this document in LaTeX, I could go to the file and just do "replace all" to swap out the old date for the new. When I recompile the document, the new images will be present in the PDF output. In Word, I learned about `INCLUDEPICTURE` [last year](https://superuser.com/questions/1647146/is-there-a-way-to-do-latex-style-image-insertions-into-ms-word), but that feature is not available in my Powerpoint (at least nowhere obvious).

Is there a way to mimic this in Powerpoint?

Comment: This question on [so] might give you some ideas [vba - Programmatically add an image to a PowerPoint file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338474/programmatically-add-an-image-to-a-powerpoint-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always the same number of images, create a new folder, put the current images into it, create a new PPT in that folder or copy an existing one into it.

For each image, choose Insert | Picture from file, browse to the folder with your images choose one and instead of clicking the Insert button at bottom right of the insert dialog, click the triangle next to it and choose either **Link To File** or **Insert and Link**

Repeat for the remaining pictures.

When it's time for new pictures, make sure the image files have the same names as the originals, copy the new files into the folder with the PowerPoint file. You may get a prompt asking for your permission to update linked content; if so, say Yes.

PPT will update your presentation with the new files.

Difference between Link To File and Insert and Link:

Link to file stores nothing but the path to the linked file within the PowerPoint file. If the pictures aren't there, you'll get a red x, no picture when you view the presentation.

Insert and Link inserts the picture from the file (so there's something to show even if the link breaks) but also checks for a new version of the file when you open the PPT file and updates if it finds one.  Unless file size is an issue, it's the better choice.

Comment: The slideshow doesn't even have to be in the same folder as the pictures! // This solves the task I have to do right now, but is there a way to update the pictures if the file name changes, perhaps with a newer date in the name or path?

Comment: Not really, or at least not that I can think of.

Comment: >> "The slideshow doesn't even have to be in the same folder as the pictures!"  Circling back to this a year later:  If you mean the PowerPoint file that holds the pictures, correct. But if it's not (at the time you create the file), then the links will almost certainly break if you move the PPT file elsewhere. By keeping them all together to begin with, you can be fairly sure that the links will continue to work, even if you move the PPT and image files to a different computer or directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that does not require learning VBA.
I assume you are on Windows, but the idea can be ported to other OS
where PowerPoint is available.
I assume that the names of the pictures are constant, so only the
folder changes each time.

- Create a placeholder directory junction named, for example `placeholder`:

  ```
  mklink /j "C:\...\Documents\placeholder" "C:\...\Documents/20220223"
  ```
- Insert the images using the "Insert and link" command,
  inserting them from `placeholder`
- When the time comes, delete `placeholder` and recreate it to point
  to the new folder:

  ```
  rmdir "C:\...\Documents\placeholder"
  mklink /j "C:\...\Documents\placeholder" "C:\...\Documents/20220225"
  ```
- Enter PowerPoint and do "Edit Links" to refresh the images.

The following references will help with the above steps:

- [The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)
- [mklink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)
- [Insert or Link Pictures in PowerPoint 2016 for Windows](https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/picturesandvisuals/2016/insert-or-link-picture.html)
- [How to Break, Update or Change Links to Excel Charts or Worksheets in PowerPoint](https://www.avantixlearning.ca/microsoft-powerpoint/how-to-break-or-update-links-to-microsoft-excel-charts-or-worksheets-in-powerpoint/)